# How can I tile horizontally certain windows programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net

In Windows 10, when I set an window on one side of the screen, I can choose which window to fix on the other side of the screen, and when I change the size of the first window, the window next to it changes simultaneously.

By the `SetWindowPos` function I can arrange a window next to a window, but my question Is there any programmatic way that when the user resizes the window that the second window will also change accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Set the first window as foreground
2. send Windows key + left arrow
3. Set the second window as foreground
4. send Windows key + right arrow